# Independence under orthogonal transformation of Gaussian matrix

Tags: probability

Suppose $G\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is a Gaussian random matrix such that all the elements are independent $N(0,1)$ distribution. Let $X=GU$ where $U\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is an orthogonal matrix. How can I prove that $X$ is also a Gaussian random matrix such that all the elements are independent $N(0,1)$ distribution?

My difficulty focus on the "independence" proof. I think following the definition of "independence" may be infeasible. Is there some easy proof? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @StubbornAtom I suspect that a Gaussian matrix is different from what you understand. At least in statistics, the definition is not "a Gaussian vector put in matrix form of some shape." See my answer below. Also note that $Ox$ and $XO$ are very different (here $x$ is a Gaussian vector and $X$ is a Gaussian vector written as a matrix of some shape). The usual rule that $\mathbf{V}(Ox) = O^\intercal \mathbf{V}(x) O$ is not carried over to $\mathbf{V}(XO) = ???$.

Answer (score 0):

For any multivariate normal r.v. $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ we have $AX \sim N(\mu, A \Sigma A^T)$ (look up "Generalizations" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) ), if $A$ is some matrix. Let $Z = A \Sigma A^T$

If $\Sigma$ is diagonal, then $Z_{ij} = \sigma_i \langle A_{i, .}, A_{., j} \rangle$, where $A_{i, .}$ means $i$-th vector of $A$, and $A_{., j}$ $j$-th column of $A$. $\sigma_i$ is element on $i$-ith position on diagonal of $\Sigma$. Then, from orthogonality $Z_{ij} = \sigma_i \delta_{ij}$, with $\delta_{ij}$ being Kronecker delta.

Hence, $Z$ is diagonal, which means that covariances between different elements in random vector are zero. In multivariate normal case this means that this components are independent.

Latter follows from the fact, that for every normally distributed $X_1, X_2$ $Cov(X_1, X_2) = 0$ is equivalent to independence between $X_1$ and $X_2$

Comment: While OP did not clarify, a Gaussian matrix is not any Gaussian vector placed in matrix form of some shape. See my answer for the usual definition.

Answer (score 0):

*Every vector here will be a column vector, so then its transpose is a row vector.*

**Usual definition of Gaussian matrix.** Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be a sample from $\mathsf{N}_p(\mu, \Sigma).$ The matrix $X = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)^\intercal$ is called a *Gaussian matrix of type $(n, p)$ from $\mathsf{N}_p(\mu, \Sigma).$*

In your case, you have $X$ a Gaussian matrix of type $(n, n)$ from $\mathsf{N}_n(0, I).$

**Theorem.** Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices of types $(m, n)$ and $(p, q).$ Let $X$ be a Gaussian matrix of type $(n, p)$ from $\mathsf{N}_p(\mu, \Sigma)$ and let $Y = AXB.$ For $Y$ to be a Gaussian matrix it is necessary and sufficient that

(a) $A \mathbf{1} =\alpha \mathbf{1}$ (the vector of ones should be an eigenvector of $A$), or $B^\intercal \mu = 0,$ and

(b) $A A^\intercal = \beta I$ (for some $\beta > 0$), or $B^\intercal \Sigma B = 0.$

When both (a) and (b) are satisfied, then $Y$ is a Gausian matrix of type $(m,q)$ from $\mathsf{N}_q(\alpha B^\intercal \mu, \beta B^\intercal \Sigma B).$

*Proof sketch.* One has to construct a vector $X^v$ by placing the columns below each other (in order) and find the mean and dispersion matrix of $X.$ It will be seens that this is possible if and only if the mean and dispersion matrix of $X$ have a special form. The two conditions follow then. For details, see *Multivariate Analysis* by Mardia, Kent, Bibby, chapter III, "Normal distribution theory", theorem 3.3.2.

In your case, since everything is independent $\mathsf{N}(0; 1),$ we see that $X$ is a Gaussian matrix of type $(n,n)$ from $\mathsf{N}_n(0, I).$ You are also taking $A = I$ and $B = U.$ Then, $A \mathbf{1} = I \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}$ and $A A^\intercal = I,$ so both properties hold. Then, $GU$ is a Gaussian matrix of type $(n, n)$ from $\mathsf{N}_n(0, U^\intercal U) = \mathsf{N}_n(0, I),$ and you are done.